# Freiheitssatz and Word Problem; a problem with literature terminology

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, combinatorial-group-theory

One of the classical achievements of the combinatorial group theory is the decidability of the word problem in a finitely generated group with one defining relation. This result was a corollary of a fundamental statement called Freiheitssatz: every equation over a free group is solvable in some extension. This is for solvable and nilpotent groups.

Freiheitssatz has been investigated for other algebraic structures.

> Is Freiheitssatz the same concept; namely, the word problem in some literature?

Comment: Do you have a citation for your statement of the Freiheitssatz, and also for usage in solvable and nilpotent groups? Classically, it isn't to do with equations but rather about generating sets of one-relator groups. (In the world of one-relator products, a Freiheitssatz refers to an embedding theorem, e.g. embeddings of $G$ and $H$ into $(G\ast H)/N$.)

Comment: Also, I do not think the Freiheitssatz should be interpreted as being about the word problem. Instead, it is the basis of an inductive method ("Magnus' method") which is *used to prove* the word problem, but this takes a page or two. Magnus' method is an important proof technique for one-relator groups which is also used to prove a whole host of other results.

Comment: @1729 The reference is a paper from Kolesnikov et al titled "The Freiheitssatz for Generic Poisson Algebras"

Comment: Ok, that's helpful (although i guess by "extension" they really mean "HNN-extension"). I have two further questions though. Firstly, how do solvable and nilpotent groups fit in? The Freiheitssatz is a "freeness theorem", so concerns free groups, while nilpotent and solvable groups contain no non-abelian free groups - they are basically irrelevant to the classical Freiheitssatz. Secondly, what do you mean by "the word problem in some literature"? Do you maybe mean "category", say, rather than "literature"?